# I want to do a solr search to see if a dynamic field exists or not

Tags: search, solr

I want to do a solr search to see if a dynamic field exists or not.

Example:

```
Doc 1 {
    Id: 111
    Name: good
    Tag_100_is: lsdkl
}


Doc 1 {
    Id: 2
    Name: not good
}
```

I want a query to retrieve doc 1.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To query for whether a field exists or not, use `field:[* TO *]`. So in this case, you should get the document you want by using the query `Tag_100_is:[* TO *]`.

If you want to get the document without the field, you'll have to invert the query (we start with *:* which are "all documents", then remove the documents that have the field):

```
q=*:* -Tag_100_is:[* TO *]
```

Comment: Sorry i want the doc without the Tag_100_is => doc not have the tag_100_is

Comment: plz 
I use solarium and to add the condition I put

$ FilterQueryAndParts ["- tags_". $id. "_ Is"] = "[* TO *]";

 I have other criteria

this request get 0 result

Comment: I'm not familiar with Solarium. Check what the query it generates actually is - it might be doing a bit of escaping for you. You can check this on the Solr side if you have the appropriate level of logging, or maybe Solarium can give you the end URL used for the request back.

Comment: last url request :

select?omitHeader=true&wt=json&json.nl=flat&q=%2A%3A%2A&start=0&rows=10&fl=userId_i&sort=userLastUpdate_date+desc&fq=type_sstr
%3Auser&fq=%5B%2A+TO+%2A%5D&fq=%5B%2A+TO+%2A%5D&facet=true&facet.field=%7B%21key%3Doap_1024_is%7Doap_1024_is&facet.field=%7B%21key%3D

Comment: There is no field name for at least two of those, so I assume you're meant to do `$filterQueryAndParts[] = "*:* -tags_...:[* TO *]"` yourself.

Comment: Solarium\Exception\InvalidArgumentException

Options value given to the setOptions() method must be an array or a Zend_Config object 
after using  $filterQueryAndParts[] = "*:* -tags_...:[* TO *]" 

!!!

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://solarium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/queries/select-query/building-a-select-query/adding-filterqueries/) the first part (the key) is just an internal key. So using `$filterQueryAndParts['somekey'] = "*:* -tags..."` should be enough. Please refer to the Solarium documentation for how to add filter queries properly.

Comment: protected 'params' => 
    array
      'omitHeader' => string 'true' (length=4)
      'wt' => string 'json' (length=4)
      'json.nl' => string 'flat' (length=4)
      'q' => string '*:*' (length=3)
      'start' => int 0
      'rows' => int 10
      'fl' => string 'userId_i' (length=8)
      'sort' => string 'userLastUpdate_date desc' (length=24)
      'fq' => 
        array
          0 => string 'type_sstr:user' (length=14)
          1 => string '*:* -tags_recruiterId_1024_is:[* TO *]' (length=38)
      'facet' => string 'true' (length=4)

Comment: Thns is OKKKKKKKKKK